# elements on html2canvas screenshot appear in a wrong way

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, fabricjs, html2canvas

Im using **html2canvas** integrated to fabricjs on a project and what happens is that: The elements apper cluttered in the screenshot when I use html2canvas together with fabricjs. On my screen they appear organized, but after the screenshot taken by html2canvas, the elements appear all disorganized and out of position.

Here's the code:

```
      html2canvas(document.querySelector(".garrafa-personalizavel"), {allowTaint: true}).then(canva => {
        // console.log(canva.toDataURL())
        let a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = canva.toDataURL('image/png')
        a.download = 'a.png'
        a.click()
        console.log(canva.toDataURL('image/png'))
      })
```

Here's the element in my screen:

[image]

Here's the screenshot that is taken by html2canvas:

[image]

Im using vue and the bottle is an svg, the structure of ".garrafa-personalizavel" is:
(i'm shortening the svg to post here for obvious reasons)

```
  <div class="garrafa-personalizavel" ref="garrafa">
    <Canva />
    <svg
      v-if="$route.params.id == 'galao1'"
      class="imagem"
      id="Camada_1"
      data-name="Camada 1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 244.64 528.21"
    ></svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Canva from "@/components/Canva.vue";
export default {
  components: { Canva },
};
</script>
```

The structure of the canva component is:

```
<div :class="`canva-${$route.params.id}`">
    <canvas :id="`canva-${$route.params.id}`"></canvas>
  </div>
```

(the canvas element is where the fabric canvas comes from).

Comment: Please show the HTML structure you are sending to html2canvas.

Comment: Sure, added it on the original post.

Comment: I was hoping to see the actual HTML.

Comment: Sorry, this is it: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/982675104850919476/989267225884127252/unknown.png